# text size does not match

Tags: tables, luatex

have a table.like.this

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\normalsize
\centering
\caption{Most Citated Countries} 
\label{tab:Most-Citated-Countries}
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrrrrl}
  \hline
 & Country & Articles & SCP & MCP & \%Freq & \%MCP & \%SCP & TGC & AAC \\ 
  \hline
 USA             & 38 & 24 & 14 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1309 &  34.45 \\ 
 CHINA           & 26 & 18 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 256 &   9.85 \\ 
 UNITED KINGDOM  & 15 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 199 &  13.27 \\ 
 ITALY           & 9 & 7 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 55 &   6.11 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and I am calling it to my main .tex file as below yet the fonts doesn't match

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,english,authoryear,1p,times,sort]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
    got lots of text here got lots of text here got lots of text here got lots of text here
\input{C:/Users/seyma/TP.2/table.like.this}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the font size the same, many thanks in advance,

Comment: Your document produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER81Q.png) why do you say the fonts do not match?

Comment: font in the table is bigger, I want to have same font size for all

Comment: No it is all 12pt as you can see in my image, or add `\showoutput` and the log will show the font of every letter. Your text is mostly lowercase and your table is mostly capitals, that's why it looks bigger. It is the same font.

Comment: change the text above to `USA CHINA UNITED KINGDOM ITALY` and you will see.